# How to zoom second TouchImageView on setOnTouchImageViewListener event of first TouchImageView?

Tags: java, android

I have two TouchImageView. What I want to do is that, When I zoom in first TouchImageView, second one also get zoom in automatically. And when I swipe from left to right or right to left on first TouchImageView, second one also need to be get swiped automatically but in reverse order. i.e If I swipe first TouchImageView from left to right, second one need to be get swiped automatically right to left. I am using TouchImageView class. My code is below. Thanks in advance.

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fb" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>


    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fb" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView.OnTouchImageViewListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TouchImageView img_to_be_zoomed;
    TouchImageView img_to_be_zoomed_mirror;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_to_be_zoomed_mirror);
        img_to_be_zoomed = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_to_be_zoomed);
        img_to_be_zoomed
                .setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMove() {
                        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setZoom(img_to_be_zoomed
                                .getCurrentZoom());
                        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setScrollPosition(
                                img_to_be_zoomed.getScaleX(), 0);
                        Log.e("Left Img X: ", "" + img_to_be_zoomed.getScaleX());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

TouchImageView.java

[TouchImageView.java Find Here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

I have achieved it for Zoom, but not getting for swiping.